# What if a player plays the ball with back surface of the bat?

Tags: cricket

If a player hits the ball with the back surface of the bat, is he given out, considering that the back of the bat is not flat? I have seen Kevin Pietersen play the switch hit, but he turns his bat around while doing it.

Comment: Why do you think they might possibly be out? What means of dismissal would this be?

Comment: Actually its a childhood rule if the player hits the ball from other side he is considered as out.We used to have this rule in our childhood :) may be OP thought the same will be followed in international level @PhilipKendall

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Law 6 (The bat)](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-6-the-bat/):

> 1. The bat
>
> **The bat consists of two parts, a handle and a blade.**

The law considers the entire bat, consisting of the handle and the blade, as one entity, and doesn't treat the front surface any different from the rest of it. You could hit the ball with the back surface or even the handle, it would be treated as a contact with the bat. Hence, the batsman would get credit for any runs scored. If a catch is cleanly taken, he would be out. Likewise, this also counts as a bat contact for other laws, such as leg before wicket.

Additionally, a hand or a glove holding the bat, as well as the handle grip, permitted advertising labels, coverings, etc. attached to the bat are also treated as "bat", in the context of contact with the ball.

> 8. Contact with the ball
>
> In these Laws,
>
> (a) reference to the bat shall imply that the bat is held in the
> batsman’s hand or a glove worn on his hand, unless stated otherwise.
>
> (b) contact between the ball and either (i) the bat itself
>
> or (ii) the batsman’s hand holding the bat
>
> or (iii) any part of a glove worn on the batsman’s hand holding the
> bat
>
> or (iv) any additional materials permitted under 3, 5 or 6 above shall
> be regarded as the ball striking or touching the bat or being struck
> by the bat.

Kevin Pietersen (or any other batsman) turns the bat while playing the switch hit because it would be nearly impossible to play the shot correctly with the bent back surface of the bat.